# Case Details Report- Active Case Role filter

Tags: civireport, civicase

Trying to run a case details report for all cases of type "x" opened between a given date range.

Noticed that not as many cases as expected show.

On further investigation found that there is a filter in the template
Active role:is equal to- options yes or no
Which effectively switches between open and closed cases

Anyone know the reason for this?

there is no option for neither, and the filter can't be removed, so I'm now left creating two reports for every case type on the system. Or creating a drupal view per case type

Comment: You want an option for neither? or for both? or for Clear?

Comment: An option not to have it as an option. If that makes sense. I'll try and put something coherent in the issue queue later.

Comment: Craig - fyi, just hit the same problem.  I get no results where it is set to Yes or No, but previously it did. Will be investigating further ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craig - it's worse than that: creating two reports with 'Yes' & 'No' will still not give you all the cases if they don't have relationships.

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/report/issues/24 and the related PR.

Comment: Thanks to Aidan's PR this is fixed in 5.22

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was added [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12711). The gist of it seems to be to address an issue when wanting to see only current staff. You might want to file an issue at lab.civicrm.org requesting a "neither" option. I don't know of a quick fix other than to see if reverting those changes listed [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/742749c58a2587e9f11ef6291e760c5c27e810b9) solve it.

Comment: Thank you. I was about to come in and delete the question. (Posted in a bout of frustration), but your answer gives me something specific to post in the lab.